Even though I upgraded, I can't get my wails application up and running
I pulled a project from git and there were no wails.json files. I created it manually but Assets: application.AssetOptions{
            Handler: application.AssetFileServerFS(assets),
        }, in this line I get the \main.go:44:25: undefined: application.AssetFileServerFS error.  When I say wails dev, I get the error shown in the image.enter image description hereenter image description here

I tried updating the package but it didn't work


![Topluluk Tarafından Doğrulandı simgesi](data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABQAAAAUCAQAAAAngNWGAAAA/0lEQVR4AYXNMSiEcRyA4cfmGHQbCZIipkuxnJgMStlMNmeyD2dwmc8+sZgxYJd9ErIZFHUyYYD7fkr6l4/rnvmtl7+KitrqV/fq2Y5eLY3Z9S48eRLe7BmVZ9qhTLhQ0algzZWQOVKSsCF8OjAnwbxDTWFDUhPK/jMr1H6HE/IqRky2DyvCefuwItwZzodVoYRiLqMkVCXrwpJ9twZ+sgfDYEFYl8wIWxZ9uFf7zkallxlJh4YrLGsKjZRx7VGHhLqwgFUN45DGdb8MeXGpgB4ABZdeDcpZEY51A+hyLKz4S1W4MQWm3AibWtgWmk6dyISa1pSdyWTOlLXVp0+eL9D/ZPfBTNanAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC)

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
